# metasploit smtp_enum: Testing different domain names

Tags: metasploit, smtp

I'm testing my SMTP server using metasploit to see what information I can extract.
Currently I'm trying to enumerate SMTP users using `smtp_enum` module.

I've encountered a problem, the server introduces itself as `mail.example.com` in the banner and metasploit uses this as a domain name, trying emails like `<something>@mail.example.com`.

Of course the server serves `example.com` domain, not to mention that it also serves several different domains.

I looked through options, documentation and several online guides, but I haven't found a way to set the domain name I want tested.

I found [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159453/metasploit-is-always-replacing-domain-names-with-resolved-ips-on-rhost-rhosts?rq=1) which discusses using `VHOST` for that purpose, but it seems `smtp_enum` doesn't have that option.

Is it possible to ignore name provided by the server in the banner and test emails like `<something>@example.com` and `<something>@otherdomain.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use metasploit for this. The `smtp-user-enum` tool should do what you are looking for. If it's not already installed in Kali, you should be able to install it using `apt install smtp-user-enum` or else you can clone the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pentestmonkey/smtp-user-enum).

Specify the `-D` flag to target the domain you need. E.g.:

`$ smtp-user-enum -D otherdomain.com -U users.txt -t example.com`

Comment: It seems to do the trick, however it uses `x` as the source host in `HELO` which makes the server reject the connection with `Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname;`. But I think I can solve this problem modifying the code. Thanks!